# Why is the audio recording on Chrome missing duration

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, ffmpeg, mediarecorder

I'm sending some user created audio to a server which later passes it to googles speech to text api for transcription. Everything works perfectly on firefox but when I try it on Chrome it doesn't work. I then installed FFmpeg to check if the metadata somehow changed for the file on chrome and noticed that the duration on the file is tagged "N/A". This does not happen on firefox.

This is the audio recorded from Chrome

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'PATH_TO_FILE':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
```

This is the audio recorded from Firefox

```
Input #0, ogg, from 'PATH_TO_FILE':
  Duration: 00:00:01.26, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 53 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Mozilla68.0
```

The audio itself is recorded using the mediarecorder-api where the blob is later converted to base64-url and sent to my server.

This is the code that I use to record the audio:

```
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(
      // constraints - only audio needed for this app
      {
        audio: true
      }
    )

    // Success callback
    .then(function(stream) {
      console.log(navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints());
      var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { sampleRate: 44100 });
      var chunks = [];
      $(".rec-button")
        .mousedown(function() {
          console.log("rec start");
          $(".rec-button i").addClass("recStart");
          mediaRecorder.start();
          console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
          console.log("recorder started");
        })
        .mouseup(function() {
          console.log("rec end");
          $(".rec-button i").removeClass("recStart");
          mediaRecorder.stop();
          mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            chunks.push(e.data);
            var blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" });
            var player = document.getElementById("player");
            player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            chunks = [];
            var reader = new window.FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = function() {
              var base64 = reader.result;
              var audioArr = {
                audio: base64
              };
              $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:4242/api/1.0/post",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(audioArr),
                success: function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              });
            };
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
            console.log("recorder stopped");
          };
        });
    })

    // Error callback
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("The following getUserMedia error occured: " + err);
    });
```

My goal is that the audio file recorded from chrome has a duration so that the google api can transcribe it. If you guys have any way of overcoming this problem I would be grateful

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012